# Mapbox GL JS Cap Zoom to Avoid Duplicate Worlds

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'd like to limit how much the user can zoom out, such that a region is never displayed twice on the map. I tried setting renderWorldCopies to false, but then the width of the map decreases when zooming out. How can I limit zooming out while keeping the map width at 100% of available width?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `minZoom` when instantiating the map:

```js
const map = mapboxgl.Map({ /*...*/,  minZoom: 2 })
```